# Bar chart from frequency of rows

Tags: r, ggplot2

I parsed a csv file in the following way:

```
chol <- read.csv("filtered.csv")
chol$X.GeneName
...                                                        
 [57] Integrase core domain containing protein                                                         
 [58] Integrase core domain containing protein                                                         
 [59] Integrase core domain containing protein                                                         
 [60] Integrase core domain containing protein                                                         
 [61] Integrase core domain containing protein                                                         
 [62] Integrase core domain containing protein                                                         
 [63] Integrase core domain containing protein                                                         
 [64] Integrase core domain containing protein                                                         
 [65] KED                                                                                              
 [66] probable haloacid dehalogenase-like hydrolase domain-containing protein 3                        
 [67] probable heat shock cognate 70 kDa protein 2-like                                                
 [68] probable heparanase-like protein 2                                                               
 [69] probable heparanase-like protein 2 isoform X1                                                    
 [70] probable heterogeneous nuclear ribonucleoprotein 1-like                                          
 [71] probable heterogeneous nuclear ribonucleoprotein 1-like                                          
 [72] probable heterogeneous nuclear ribonucleoprotein 1-like                                          
 [73] probable heterogeneous nuclear ribonucleoprotein 1-like
...
```

Next, I would like to calculate the frequency of the same lines and plot them as bar chart.

How is it possible to calculate the frequency?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `as.data.frame(table(chol$X.GeneName))`

Comment: `library(tidyverse); chol %>% count(X.GeneName) %>% ggplot(aes(X.GeneName, n)) + geom_col() + coord_flip()` : is that your desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# making more reproducible
x <- seq(1, 17, 1)
X.GeneName<- c( "Integrase core domain containing protein",                                                       
"Integrase core domain containing protein",                                                      
"Integrase core domain containing protein",                                                       
"Integrase core domain containing protein",                                                      
"Integrase core domain containing protein",                                                       
"Integrase core domain containing protein",                                                      
"Integrase core domain containing protein",                                                       
"Integrase core domain containing protein",                                                      
"KED",                                                                                              
"probable haloacid dehalogenase-like hydrolase domain-containing protein 3",                      
"probable heat shock cognate 70 kDa protein 2-like",                                                
"probable heparanase-like protein 2",                                                              
"probable heparanase-like protein 2 isoform X1",                                                    
"probable heterogeneous nuclear ribonucleoprotein 1-like",                                          
"probable heterogeneous nuclear ribonucleoprotein 1-like",                                        
"probable heterogeneous nuclear ribonucleoprotein 1-like",                                          
"probable heterogeneous nuclear ribonucleoprotein 1-like")

chol <- data.frame(x,X.GeneName)
```

More formatting or another column as a key might be needed, but try:

```
ggplot(chol, aes(X.GeneName)) + geom_histogram(stat = "count") +
                     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, 
                     hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Good idea by @Stephan adding the coord_flip() to accommodate the long names:

```
ggplot(df, aes(X.GeneName)) + geom_histogram(stat = "count") +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + coord_flip()
```

[image]